# How to stop (c) becoming copyright © in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, special-characters, xamarin-binding

I am binding string to label's text property. and string is containing (C). but when it's loading on Label it's converted to copyright symbol ©.

Code Snippets:

```
<ContentPage>
    <Label Text="This is Testing for copyright (c)"/>
</ContentPage>
```

**Note**: It's showing copyright symbol if we used custom fonts. I using Manrope-Bold.ttf font in app.

Comment: I did  test,but I couldn't reproduce this problem. Could you please post some code snippets so that we can test on our side?

Comment: Hi @JessieZhang-MSFT I updated question with code snippets

Comment: Hi @JessieZhang-MSFT,  it's showing special character if we used custom font's. I am using Manrope-Bold.ttf font in app

Comment: I think the font just has a dedicated glyph for the sequence `(c)`, so this happens **purely** when rendering. This is called a ligature and is a feature of the font. You could theoretically probably turn of usage of ligatures, but that would have some unexpected results as well (for example `fi` is often aligature in fonts to improve readability of this letter-combination, other examples exist). See [this font page](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Manrope?preview.text=(c)%20vs%20%C2%A9&preview.text_type=custom) for a demonstration.